# How to implement Flick gesture in Android in Touch mode?

Tags: android, gesture, android-gesture

I want to know how to implement Flick gesture in Touch mode in Android, I have searched a lot about this but didn't find anything Related to my requirement.

Comment: You can use onFling method in the GestureDetector listener callback to detect the swipe direction and velocity. Based upon the desired velocity threshold and the fling direction, you can treat it as Flick.